# Trying to use Vbscript to find data within excel and select its value from a dropdownlist within an HTA

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vbscript, hta

I would first like to add that I am very new to vbscript so sorry if this is something simple that I am missing. Ive searched but having issues coming up with the correct code (although this site has helped me a tremendous amount).

Anyway, I have created an HTA that you can enter data into a form and have it populate an excel spreadsheet. If the serial number is already in the spreadsheet then it updates the column, otherwise it adds a new column. All this is working fine. I am trying to add a SUB so i can have a search button to populate the fields so you can see what data is already in there before updating it. I am able to get the text box's to populate but the dropdown lists fail to select the matching value. Here is the section of the code that populates the form. If i change the dropdowns to text input then it populates fine. I placed to arrows to the left of the two lines that are failing, I have tried many different things but they all seem to fail. Hopefully that all makes sense. Thanks in advance!

```
  Sub SearchINV()
    Dim FSO, oExcel, oData, FoundCell, FindTag, FilePath, oWorkSheet

    FindTag = document.all.serial.value
    FilePath = "C:\file.xlsx"


    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oData = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    oData.Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Set FoundCell = oData.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A20000").Find(FindTag)
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set FoundCell = oData.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A20000").Find(FindTag)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
      Dim r, c
      r = FoundCell.Row
      c = FoundCell.Column  
      Set oWorkSheet = oData.Worksheets("sheet1")
      document.getElementById("serial").value = FoundCell.Value
      document.getElementById("combination").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+1).Value
      document.getElementById("last").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+2).Value
      document.getElementById("first").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+3).Value
      document.getElementById("department").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+4).Value
--->  document.getElementById("floor").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+5).Value
--->  document.getElementById("building").value = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+6).Value
    Else
      MsgBox (FindTag & " not found")
    End If

    Set File_Path = nothing
    Set FindTag = nothing
    Set FoundCell = nothing
    oData.Close
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oWorkSheet = Nothing
    Set oData = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the information you provided is rather incomplete I can give you only a generic answer on how to populate dropdown lists.

A dropdown list in HTML is a `<select>` element, and the items listed in the dropdown list are `<option>` elements. The HTML code looks somewhat like this:

```
<select id="fruit">
  <option value="green">Apple</option>
  <option value="yellow" selected>Banana</option>
  <option value="red">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

The presence of an attribute `selected` indicates that an option is selected.

To populate a dropdown list you need to add `<option>` elements to the `<select>` element, e.g. like this:

```
'sample data
data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
data.Add "green" , "Apple"
data.Add "yellow", "Banana"
data.Add "red"   , "Strawberry"

'get dropdown list element
Set list = document.getElementById("fruit")

'populate dropdown list with sample data
For Each fruit In data.Keys
  Set opt = document.createElement("OPTION")
  opt.Text  = data(fruit)
  opt.Value = fruit
  list.Add opt
Next
```

If that doesn't help you need to provide more information about your source data, the elements you want to populate, and how the result should look like.

---

**Edit:** If you want to select an option from an already populated dropdown list if it matches the value of a given cell from an Excel spreadsheet you'd do it like this:

```
'get dropdown list element
Set list = document.getElementById("fruit")

'select matching element
For Each opt In list.Options
  If opt.Text = oWorksheet.Cells(r, c+5).Value Then opt.Selected = True
Next
```

Comment: thanks for the response,  it seems i need to give some more information but I am not real sure how to word it. Your code above (i believe) defines the choices for the dropdown box. I have the html set up with all the options (for exable A B C), I am trying to get the two lines above to grab the existing data from an excel document and select the matching option from the dropdown.

So say i have options A, B, and C. The excel document currently has A in the cell. When you open the HTA, i would like it to automatically select A in that dropdown list.

Comment: this worked exactly as I was hoping for. I really appreciate the help!